# Access Excel SQL Insert Into Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I try to import data from specific MS-Excel data cells (A2, B2, C2) into a MS-Access Table. It does work with the following Code:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tbl_01] ( Import01, Import02, Import03 ) VALUES('" & strImport01 & "', '" & strImport02 & "', '" & strImport03 & "')"
```

Only problem is, that it inserts the data into an new dataset on that Access Table. But I want to achieve that the data crom Excel should be inserted into the selected dataset (ID) on the Access-form "query1" .. I am not sure why it won't work. Do you have an idea?

Here is the complete VBA code:

```vb
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim strImport01 As String
Dim strImport02 As String
Dim strImport03 As String
Dim fileName As String
Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets(1)
fileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.xlsx"

strImport01 = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
strImport02 = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
strImport03 = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range("C2")

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tbl_01] ( Import01, Import02, Import03 ) VALUES('" & strImport01 & "', '" & strImport02 & "', '" & strImport03 & "') SELECT ID WHERE ID =" & [Forms]![query1]![ID]"
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you're looking for an `update` statement. Alternatively maybe you just want to delete all records before re-importing them from Excel.

Comment: yes, I think you are right. I didn't tought about that.

my solution now:
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tbl_01] SET Import01 = '" & strImport01 & "' , Import02 = '" & strImport02 & "', Import03 = '" & strImport03 & "' WHERE ID =" & [Forms]![query1]![ID]

Comment: and thank you GolezTrol .. you saved me some time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anybody who has the same or any similar problem .. my solution with the UPDATE Statement:

```
fileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.xlsx" 
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim strImport01 As String
Dim strImport02 As String
Dim strImport03 As String

Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets(1)

strImport01 = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
strImport02 = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
strImport03 = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range("C2")

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [tbl_01] " & _
" SET Import01 = '" & strImport01 & "' , Import02 = '" & strImport02 & "', Import03 = '" & strImport03 & "' " & _
" WHERE ID =" & [Forms]![query1]![ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move

```
fileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.xlsx"
```

to the top.

```
Dim strImport01 As String
Dim strImport02 As String
Dim strImport03 As String
Dim fileName As String

fileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\test.xlsx"
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets(1)
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead yours

there is no need for Select after where clause

```
" INSERT INTO [tbl_01] " _ 
        & "( Import01, Import02, Import03 ) VALUES(" _ 
    & strImport01 & "', '" & strImport02 & "', '" & strImport03 & ")" _
        & "WHERE ID =" & [Forms]![query1]![ID];"
```